# How to make progressbar works in python?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, gtk, progress-bar

Imagine I want to make a simple program with GUI like this.
[image]

this is my code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import gobject

class gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.window.add(self.box)

        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.box.pack_start(self.progressbar, True, True, 0)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='Start')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)

        self.window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        self.task = self.iters(100000)
        gobject.idle_add(self.task.next)

    def iters(self, j):
        i = j
        while i > 0 :
            i -= 1
            print i
            self.progressbar.set_fraction((j - float(i)) / j)
            yield True
        yield False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = gui()
```

I know how to make progressbar work if I put everything in one script like that.
But, what if I want to separate gui part from logic part? So, it would be like this:

GUI.py

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class gui():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        self.box = Gtk.Box()
        self.window.add(self.box)

        self.progressbar = Gtk.ProgressBar()
        self.box.pack_start(self.progressbar, True, True, 0)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='Start')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)

        self.window.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        //how to implement it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = gui()
```

Iteration.py

```
class Iteration():
def iters(self, j):
    i = j
    while i > 0 :
        i -= 1
        print i
```

**EDIT:**
One more thing, the first code above works, but why do I get this message:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
import gobject._gobject
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, imagine I have one module like this one:
Works.py

```
def getImageFromInternet(uri):
    #some code to get image from internet
```

this `getImageFromInternet` function is not iterable. What I want to do is processing this function in the background while updating the progressbar and doing other thing with gui. Do I need a thread for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a generator that updates the GUI and drives the underlying data model generator, and pass that to `idle_add`. For example (untested):

```
    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        cnt = 10000
        task = self.iters(cnt)
        def gui_iter():
            for i, ignore in enumerate(task, 1):
                self.progressbar.set_fraction(i / cnt)
                yield True
            yield False
        gobject.idle_add(gui_iter().next)
```

Comment: didn't work for me. this is what i've got: `line 21, in progress
    for i, ignore in enumerate(t, 1):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: @user2435611 I only now notice that your `iters()` is not an iterator. Why not?

Comment: it's just a sample because the real task will not be iterable.

Comment: @user2435611 So, why not make it iterable? Your stated goal was to decouple the data model from the user interface, which is achieved with the design as shown (no user interface code is in dm). If your code is not iterable, it will be significantly harder to convert to show progress. The next thing to try is running it in a thread.

Comment: Imagine that I have one class that have a function doing such a heavy works that is not iterable. so, I can't do it with idle_add()?

Comment: @user2435611 `idle_add` will not work because the function it invokes must be of short duration, as GUI is not refreshed while it is running. You either need to do a longer calculation in a separate thread, or use a single thread, but provide the calculation with a callback function that it will occasionally code to indicate progress. Which of these two approaches is more appropriate depends on the situation and likely warrants a separate question.